# System has crashed, terminal showing 'configuring secure boot' box

Tags: apt

I tried upgrading xfce desktop with -

```
sudo apt-get upgrade xfce4
```

For unknown reasons the process was not completed. After it whenever I tried issuing a `sudo apt-get` command, it resulted in -

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Now my entire system has no icons, not a single one. Some packages must have not been installed. Some research resulted in two solutions.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This resulted in a box (I don't know whether it is an error box or an instruction box.) I tried taking a screenshot, but alas! Couldn't take it also. I've copy pasted the text here.

```
Configuring Secure Boot   
 │ Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                                   
 │                                                                             
 │ UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with             
 │ third-party drivers.                                                        
 │                                                                             
 │ The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. To permit       
 │ the use of third-party drivers, a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been      
 │ generated. This key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware.     
 │                                                                             
 │ To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user,      
 │ and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then confirm     
 │ the change after reboot using the same password, in both the "Enroll        
 │ MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus that will be presented to you     
 │ when this system reboots.                                                   
 │                                                                             
 │                                  <Ok>
```

Please guide me what should I do, whether I should reinstall the whole system, or still there is some way by which I can handle this.

Comment: The last text paste in your question is a set of instructions, not an error. It is asking you to set a password for MOK because your (I'm assuming laptop?) has either drive encryption or drive recovery built-in. You will need to set a password, and ***remember it.***

Comment: but I've a password, I don't know what is this MOK & yes, I've a laptop.

Comment: I would recommend [reading up](https://firmware.intel.com/blog/using-mok-and-uefi-secure-boot-suse-linux) before you go any further. Machine owner keys are used to ensure that your data stays safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to BIOS of your system by pressing ESC or f2 (key depends on company model, asus-f2,. Hp-esc etc) on startup. Find the 'Secure Boot' option and disable it.
Then again do the 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`